# Getting standard deviation on a specific number of dates

Tags: pandas

In this dataframe...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

tf = 365
dt = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=365)

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Cat': np.repeat(['a', 'b', 'c'], tf),
        'Date': np.tile(pd.date_range(dt, periods=tf), 3),
        'Val': np.random.rand(3*tf)
})
```

How can I get a dictionary of standard deviation of each 'Cat' values for a specific number of days - back from the last day for a large dataset?

This code gives the standard deviation for 10 days...

```
{s: np.std(df[(df.Cat == s) & 
          (df.Date > today-datetime.timedelta(days=10))].Val) 
for s in df.Cat.unique()}
```

...looks clunky.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate [`std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html), but because default value `ddof=1` is necessary set it to `0`:

```
d1 = df[(df.Date>dt-datetime.timedelta(days=10))].groupby('Cat')['Val'].std(ddof=0).to_dict()
print (d1)
{'a': 0.28435695432581953, 'b': 0.2908486860242955, 'c': 0.2995981283031974}
```

Another solution is use custom function:

```
f = lambda x: np.std(x.loc[(x.Date > dt-datetime.timedelta(days=10)), 'Val'])
d2 = df.groupby('Cat').apply(f).to_dict()
```

Difference between solutions is if some values in group not matched conditions then is removed and for second solution is assignd `NaN`:

```
d1 = {'b': 0.2908486860242955, 'c': 0.2995981283031974}

d2 = {'a': nan, 'b': 0.2908486860242955, 'c': 0.2995981283031974}
```